# Ajax request taking too long time

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ajax request is taking too long to give response back

Jquery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#contactForm').on('submit', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo site_url;?>includes/listContact.php",
            data:$("#contactForm input").serialize(),//only input
            success: function(response){

                    $('#thankMsg').show();
                    $('#hidediv1').hide();
                }
        });


    });

 });
</script>
```

and this is the page which is requested by ajax code:

```
$file3 = file_get_contents('a.txt', true);
$data3=json_decode($file3,true);
$to=$data3['email'];
$subject="*********************";

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:  <'.$to.'>' . "\r\n";



$message="Hi, <br/><br/>";
$message .="*********************** <br/><br/>";
foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
$message .="<strong>".ucfirst(str_replace('_',' ',$key)).":</strong>        $value<br/>";
}
$message .="<br/><br/><strong>Thanks</strong><br/>";


if(mail ("$to", "$subject", "$message", "$headers"))
{
 echo "done";
}
else
{
 echo "no";
}
```

Taking almost 10-12 seconds to get the response? I didn't found any problem in this code...as its very simple script and data sent by ajax is only input fields value.

Thanks

Comment: Try running the PHP script itself without the AJAX call. Do you still get a very slow response?

Comment: @Terry yes its taking time

Comment: Then you can discount the possibility of a client-side code issue. How big the is `$_POST` object? You're looping through it.

Comment: fields are created dynamically that's why i have to use looping

Comment: How many of them are you sending when it takes this long? Tens, hundreds, thousands?

Comment: Is it slow if you comment out the `mail()` call? I'm just trying to diagnose where the slowness is.

Comment: their are 6 only @Barmar

Answer (score 3):

Your slowness is most likely in the `mail()` function. Sending mail often takes a long time, even if the message is not very large.  To confirm this, try commenting out your `mail(...)` and just do `echo "done"`. Then see if it is now super fast.

Depending on your server, mail() might be piping input to sendmail locally, or it might be connecting to an SMTP server.

I recommend you try PHPMailer, which allows you to specify SMTP or sendmail explicitly, or to use the built-in mail() function. (PHPMailer also takes care of the MIME header and lots of other useful things.)

You could then do speed tests to see which of SMTP or sendmail is faster, then go with the faster one. If you are constrained to using SMTP, then PHPMailer lets you specify some faster server to send through.